# SXA Search Results First Element

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

I have a SXA Search Result component and I want to apply a specific class to first element from the search results on every page. Is it a simple way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need a class? Maybe it's possible with css like https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/ ?

Comment: I have a faq list and the first element should be expanded, that's the reason I need a class.